# Dashbox text positioning

Tags: graphics, positioning

can someone tell me how to fine position the text inside a dashbox. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}                               
\usepackage{graphicx}       

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(380,320)

\put(10,0){\dashbox{2.5}(360,100)[tl] {Core-Standards}}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

It doesn´t look good I want the text top left but it intersects with the dotted square, I want the text a little bit to the right and down:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert a vertical `\strut` and some horizontal space using (say) `\,`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}                               
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(380,320)
  \put(10,0){\dashbox{2.5}(360,100)[tl] {Core-Standards (original)}}
  \put(10,110){\dashbox{2.5}(360,100)[tl] {\strut\,Core-Standards (updated)}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

If you wish to push it down even further, you can increase the strut to the height you want with `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` where you specify `<height>`. `\strut` has a `<height>` of `.7\baselineskip` (and is therefore font-dependent).

Horizontal adjustment is possible using `\rule{<width>}{0pt}`. `\,` inserts a horizontal space of width `\thinskipamount`. Using `\hspace*{<width>}` would also work.

Comment: Thank you very much Werner, now it finally looks like I want it.

Answer (score 3):

The following example defines and uses `\padbox` that adds a padding using `\fbox` with an invisible border (rule width set to zero). Also care is taken, that `\fbox` is working within the argument of `\padbox`. This way the text is surrounded with white space on all sides and avoids the clashing into any border of the dash box. The padding can be configured by setting the length `\padboxsep`. It is initialized with the value of `\fboxsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newdimen\padboxsep
\setlength{\padboxsep}{\fboxsep}
\newcommand*{\padbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\restorefbox{%
      \fboxrule=\the\fboxrule\relax
      \fboxsep=\the\fboxsep\relax
    }%
    \fboxrule=0pt %
    \fboxsep=\padboxsep
    \fbox{\restorefbox#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(380,320)

\put(10,110){\dashbox{2.5}(360,100)[tl] {Core-Standards \fbox{original}}}

\put(10,0){\dashbox{2.5}(360,100)[tl] {\padbox{Core-Standards \fbox{padbox}}}}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % set the unit of picture environment

\begin{picture}(0,0)
  \dashbox{1}(50,20)[c]{your text her}
\end{picture}

% (50,20) : this correspond to width and height of the dashbox
% [c] : this correspond to text adjustment, you can use [l] or [r] ...  

\end{document}
```